# How can I see View Controllers chain in MonoDevelop debugger?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

For example, I've pushed view controller then, pushed another one, then popped, then another 3 pushes and 1 pop.
How can I see resulting view controllers "stack"? 
And how can I see which view controller will appear when I press "back button" on top bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UINavigationController` exposes the 'stack' of view controllers via the `ViewControllers` array property. See the following documentation:

http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UINavigationController.ViewControllers

To find the view controller that will be navigated to, just take the last element from this array.

Comment: I'll accept this, but please, never remove answer in the post to give an answer. That's just not fair.

Comment: @folex - If you look at my edit, it has the comment "Answers should be posted as ... answers! Even if you answer your own question.". It is perfectly OK to answer your own question, but you should actually submit this as an answer that can then be accepted and upvoted. .... I was not just doing it for the points! ;-)